# how not to end the program when user enters Ok on QMessageox in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have Mainwindow and Messagebox. On clicking Ok on messagebox, I want to close the messagebox and hide the mainwindow. Post that I want to launch the Main window based on certain condition. But this line self.msg.exec_() or self.msg.show(), ending the program with Process finished with exit code 0. I don't want to end the Mainwindow, just want to hide it and launch it again.

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class Main(QMainWindow):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)

    self.Close = QPushButton('Close', self)
    self.Close.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    self.Close.setStyleSheet(
        'QPushButton {background-color: Gray;}')
    self.Close.clicked.connect(lambda: self.popup_close())
    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(self.Close)
    self.centralwidget.setLayout(vbox)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.show()

def popup_close(self):
    self.msg = QMessageBox()
    self.msg.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint)
    self.msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)

    self.msg.setText("Warning.")
    self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
    if self.msg == QMessageBox.Ok:
        self.msg.accept()
        self.hide()    #hide the main window on closing the warning popup
    self.msg.show()
# self.msg.exec_()
#resp = time_api.api_calls.isSubmitted(self)
#if resp['isLocked'] == True and resp['submitted'] == True:
#   Main()
```

```
class Starter():
   def start(self):
       app = QApplication(sys.argv)
       Main()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
   s = Starter()
   s.start()
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Edited the source code. please have a look. Thankyou